# How can I make jquery elements working of generated elements after dom loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Part of my dom will be created after page loaded *(by ajax)*. For those generated-dom-after-page-load, my code doesn't work (nothing happens). Here is my code:

```
var doc = $(document);
var hold_trigger = $('.qandacontent, tr[id^="comment-"], div[class] > p:not([class])');

hold_trigger.mousedown(function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), hold_time);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```

And here is my new code after some researches:

```
var doc = $(document);
var hold_trigger = $('.qandacontent, tr[id^="comment-"], div[class] > p:not([class])');

doc.on("mousedown", hold_trigger, function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), hold_time);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```

But it throws this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument.menu_toggle

Any idea how can I fix it?

---

And here is `menu_toggle` function:

```
function menu_toggle() {
    var curr_url = window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, "");
    if ( $(this).is("tr") ){
        url_of_elem = curr_url + "#" + $(this).attr("id");
        $(".elm_url > h3").html($(".elm_url > h3").text().replace(/بخش|پست/,"پیام"));
    } else {
        url_of_elem = curr_url + "#" + $(this).siblings("table[id]").attr("id").replace("table","post");
        $(".elm_url > h3").html($(".elm_url > h3").text().replace(/بخش|پیام/,"پست"));
    }  

    document.getElementById("elm_url_input").value = decodeURI(url_of_elem);
    hold_menu.fadeIn(100);
    document.getElementById("elm_url_input").select();
}
```

Comment: What's the `menu_toggle` function?

Comment: The error occours on `menu_toggle`. Can you provide more code or a jsfiddle? The snippets are not enough to get a clear sight on the issue

Comment: I've added that function to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your whole issue, but this is definitely an issue.

```
var doc = $(document);
var hold_trigger = $('.qandacontent, tr[id^="comment-"], div[class] > p:not([class])');

doc.on("mousedown", hold_trigger, function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), hold_time);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Notice this part: `doc.on("mousedown", hold_trigger, function() {`
You are trying to give a jQuery object as the second parameter to the `on()`.  This is not valid for a delegate binding.  It expects a string containing a selector, the purpose of which being that selector will be applied against every event that bubbles up to the parent to see if it matches the element the event originated from.  If it matches, it will process the event against that element.

This should be changed so you just give it the selector.

```
var doc = $(document);

doc.on("mousedown", '.qandacontent, tr[id^="comment-"], div[class] > p:not([class])', function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), hold_time);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```

Comment: True, it works thank you. Just for my information, can't I make a selector of `hold_trigger` variable? *(which is a jquery object)*

Comment: You could make it an actual string variable, but no, you should not provide it as a jQuery object.  The whole point of the delegate is to give the selector for matching against elements that potentially do not exist yet.  Trying to select them ahead of time does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in `on()` function should be a selector, not a jquery object. So it works:

```
var doc = $(document);

doc.on('mousedown', '.qandacontent, tr[id^="comment-"], div[class] > p:not([class])', function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), hold_time);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```